# how can i display super and subscript values as labels in JSX graph

Tags: jsxgraph

I wants to display a geometry question with Latex text like x^2 - 3 in the place of side length.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscripts and superscripts should work out of the box, see e.g.http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wiki/index.php/Texts.
For more complicated math texts, you can use MathJax, see e.g. http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wiki/index.php/Using_MathJax.